# Designing XML - confused between attributes and elements

Tags: c#, .net, xml, scheme

I have to design an xml structure to set standard data exchange with my client.

We deal with payments and its related data.

At now, my XML data looks like this:

```
<PAYMENTS>
 <CURRENCY>DOLLARS</CURRENCY>
 <PAYMENTTYPE>CHEQUE</PAYMENTTYPE>
 <PAYMENT>
   <AMOUNT>100</AMOUNT>
   // ALL OTHER DETAILS GO HERE
 </PAYMENT>
 <PAYMENT>
   <AMOUNT>100</AMOUNT>
   // ALL OTHER DETAILS GO HERE
 </PAYMENT>
</PAYMENTS>
```

But one of my colleague managed to write a different version.

```
<PAYMENTS CURRENCY = DOLLARS 
          PAYMENTTYPE = CHEQUE>
 <PAYMENT>
   <AMOUNT>100</AMOUNT>
   // ALL OTHER DETAILS GO HERE
 </PAYMENT>
 <PAYMENT>
   <AMOUNT>100</AMOUNT>
   // ALL OTHER DETAILS GO HERE
 </PAYMENT>
</PAYMENTS>
```

(The `currency` and `paymenttype` tags are moved as attributes because they are not going to repeat again like `payment`)

But, I wonder what is the best method to represent this ? My way or the second one?

Are there any guidelines to this?

(Not sure if this helps: But, I am using C# for coding)

Comment: Check out this q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241819/xml-best-practices-attributes-vs-additional-elements

Comment: And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746/xml-attribute-vs-xml-element

Comment: In your particular example, the attributes seem to be describing each individual `PAYMENT`, rather than the whole body of `PAYMENTS` so it doesn't make sense to have them at that level - what if one payment happens to be a different payment type or currency? Anyway, personally I'd make the currency and payment type as additional elements on each payment - that way each payment is a self-contained entity, and may be easier to parse (IMHO). Imagine if you wanted to combine two sets of payments into one - it would not work unless both had the same currency and paymenttype.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp good point. Thanks. But, for all the `payment` inside `payments` have a `single currency` and `paymenttype`. So, that should not be a problem :)

Comment: Yes, you said that in your question. I'm just pointing out that hardcoding that assumption into your design now may prove to be a limiting factor in the future; whereas a more general design (one that allows combining different payment types in the same document) *may* be better in the long run. BUT, you know your system better than me.

Comment: @downvoter: care to comment ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the number one problem of using XML as a data serialization format! Attributes vs contained elements - so useful in markup, so annoying in data serialization...

At any rate, assuming you are forced to go with the herd and use XML for data serialization, there are only three reasons to prefer attributes over elements:

- If the field has it's own subfields.
- If the field can repeat.
- If the field is something you want to treat as [heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heredoc).

All these cases apply for the design, not for the example set of data you have in hand. If a field in your data doesn't happen to follow any of these rules, but the design allows one of the rules to apply it, it should be an element.

The reason to prefer attributes over elements(unless one of the cases apply) is that even with LINQ to XML it's much easier to use attributes. Programming languages usually make it easier to say "I have an object, give me the contents of one of it's fields" than to say "Here is a pile of objects, fetch me one that fits a certain criteria".

Both `CURRENCY` and `PAYMENTTYPE` are - as you say - non-repeatable by design, and they are not compound, and they don't really need to be heredoc - so they should, by all means, be attributes. So should be, by the way, `AMOUNT` of `PAYMENT`, so you should probably write:

```
<PAYMENTS CURRENCY = "DOLLARS"
    PAYMENTTYPE = "CHEQUE">
    <PAYMENT AMOUNT="100">
        // ALL OTHER DETAILS GO HERE
    </PAYMENT>
    <PAYMENT AMOUNT="100">
        // ALL OTHER DETAILS GO HERE
    </PAYMENT>
</PAYMENTS>
```

and consider which of these "ALL OTHER DETAILS" should really "GO HERE", and which should also be attributes.